# ImageView changes position on rotation

Tags: android, rotation

I have an two images in a relative layout. Image 2 is placed inside image 1. I want both images to rotate. Image one rotates perfectly but image 2 changes its position on rotation. Image 2 does not rotate around its original center.

java code

```
 ImageView playcircle = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playcircle);
ImageView animationcircle =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.animationcircle);
Animation a = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.linear_interpolator);
playcircle.startAnimation(a); 
animationcircle.startAnimation(a) ;
```

XML  code

```
<RelativeLayout..................>

    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/playcircle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/mainmenu_play_circle" />

        <ImageView
             android:id="@+id/animationcircle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"

            android:layout_margin="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/mainmenu_animation" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How are you rotating them? Could you provide some code/xml ?

Comment: Why don't you try `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i just made demo for rotation

**activty_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_delete_icon" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iv2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:padding="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Bind button Click and wrote some code for rotation like

```
btnRotate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 360,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
                        Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
                rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
                rotateAnimation1.setDuration(2000);
                rotateAnimation1.setRepeatCount(0);
                iv1.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
                iv2.startAnimation(rotateAnimation1);
            }
        });
```

Comment: 1. image 2 is inside image 1 
2. Even in this case image is not rotating in a fixed position like image 1

Comment: Have you try to change Layout from LinearLayout to RelativeLayout?

Comment: yes originally I was doing that. But problem of second image not rotating around center of original position  persists

Comment: Use android:padding="60dp"instead of android:layout_margin="60dp". I just edited my above answer. It is works at my end

Comment: pivotX, pivotY is the key here.